# Deformation retracts induces deformation retract on quotient

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm reading the following proof in Hatcher:

[image]

How does a deformation retract of $V$ onto $A$ give a deformation retract of $V/A$ onto $A/A$?

So, let $r: V \to A$ be a retract and $1_V \sim r$. How do I get a retract $V/A \to A/A$? Is it simply mapping all of $V/A$ to $A \in A/A = \{A\}$?

Comment: Let $r:V\to A$ be a retract such that $H:i\circ r\simeq \text{Id}_V$, where $i:A\hookrightarrow V$ is the inclusion. Then, consider $q\circ H$, where $q:V\to V/A$ is the quotient map.

Comment: But I need a map $V/A \to A/A$ not a map $V \to A/A$ right?

Comment: Yeah, you have to consider the following fact. If, $f,g:(W,W')\to (Z,Z')$ are maps of pairs that are homotopic through maps of pairs, then the induced maps $\big(W/W',*\big)\to \big(Z/Z',*\big)$ are also homotopic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If, $f,g:(W,W')\to (Z,Z')$ are maps of pairs that are homotopic
> through maps of pairs, then the induced maps $\big(W/W',*\big)\to
>  \big(Z/Z',*\big)$ are also homotopic.

To prove it, let $H:W\times [0,1]\to W$ be such a homotopy, i.e. $H(\bullet, 0)=f$ and $H(\bullet, 1)=g$ with $H(w',t)\in Z'$ for all $w'\in W'$ and all $t\in [0,1]$. Now, consider the map $$\widetilde H:W/W'\times [0,1]\to Z/Z'\text{ defined by}$$$$\big(\text{cls}(w),t\big)\longmapsto \text{cls}\big(H(w,t)\big)$$

Let $q_Z:Z\to Z/Z'$ and $q_W:W\to W/W'$ be quotient maps. Note that $\widetilde H\circ \big(q_W\times \text{Id}_{[0,1]}\big)=q_Z\circ H$. Hence, $\widetilde H\circ \big(q_W\times \text{Id}_{[0,1]}\big)$ is continuous. But, $q_W\times \text{Id}_{[0,1]}$ is a quotient map as $[0,1]$ is locally compact Hausdorff space. Hence, $\widetilde H$ is continuous.

Comment: Maybe one additional question: Why is $\tilde{H}$ continuous?

Comment: Check the answer again.

Comment: Thank you! That helped!